# Receiving shortwave frequencies from different countries (e.g. North Korea)

Tags: hf, receiver, frequency, swl

This question may be a little strange, but how can I receive radio waves from a country like North Korea (when I live in Poland)? I am interested in this topic, but I don't have that much knowledge. Can I use any radio working on UHF/VHF or do I need some other equipment using a different range? I will be grateful for any answer!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The frequencies in your pasted image of a table are in kilohertz (kHz).  These days frequencies are more often expressed in megahertz or gigahertz (MHz or GHz).  Anyway, frequencies ranging from 3560 kHz, also known as 3.56 MHz, to 15.245 MHz are in the high-frequency (HF) band, also commonly called "shortwave", rather than the very-high-frequency (VHF) or ultra-high-frequency (UHF) bands, which generally range from 30 MHz to 3 GHz (also known as 3000 MHz).

So if you have a radio that receives on the VHF and UHF bands, then you won't be able to receive the Voice of Korea from Poland.  A shortwave radio would work better, but you might have trouble receiving the signal in urban areas because the RF noise from modern electronics has gotten so bad.  These days, many shortwave broadcasters also make their broadcasts available via internet.  (I didn't see any way to stream the broadcast over the internet with a quick scan of the Voice of Korea's web site.)

A local amateur radio club could be an excellent resource for setting up a shortwave receiver; they could give you valuable advice on the best time of day and band to listen, and help you with antennas.  An external wire antenna would probably work much better than the built-in whip antennas that many shortwave receivers have.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I live on flat terrain, in an area of about 30km there are no buildings around, so I can easily put up the antenna. Could you advise what receivers you could recommend? I've heard that TECSUN receivers like TECSUN PL880 work quite well. Could you give me some receiver models so I don't make a mistake (as I understand that old receivers from the USSR from the 80s unfortunately won't do :D).As for the antenna, it has to be a long-wire antenna, for example 40m, 50m? Or maybe a loop antenna might be suitable too?

Comment: Because I understand that I need a receiver operating on shortwave frequencies of 1711-29999 kHz? (1.7 Mhz - 30 MHz)

Comment: You're welcome!  If you like an answer, please consider upvoting it, and if you feel that an answer has answered your question sufficiently, then please consider "accepting" it by clicking on the check mark.  But I recommend not accepting an answer until at least 24 or 48 hours have passed, in order to keep attracting more answers.

Comment: I will definitely accept it! I'll still leave it for now, as it's possible that there will be some more responses :)

Comment: Sorry, I can't really recommend a shortwave receiver, because I have only listened through ham transceivers that also transmit, which cost more than receivers.  I think you'd get better antenna advice from local hams who can see your situation and know your conditions.  The traditional shortwave antenna is a long wire, and 40 or 50 m should work fine.  Please know that you need a good ground with a long wire antenna, either a wire of about the same length running along the ground underneath the wire in the air, or at least a connection to a metal pipe that makes contact with earth.

Comment: You can upvote all the answers, if there are more than one, but you can only accept one.